# How to set different widget icon upon resize

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-icons

I have a widget icon for different screen sizes put in folders **drawable-mdpi/drawable-xhdpi** etc.

Lets say device has mdpi-screen, so android will display my `1x1` widget using `drawable-mdpi/widget_pic.png [48x48px]`

And when I resize widget to `2x2` it will use the same icon but will put in in the center without scaling. 
I want android to see that widget size became 2x larger and choose an icon from resources accordingly (i.e. `drawable-xhdpi/widget_pic.png[96x96px]`).

***So my question is how to do it?*** 
I can think of a solution but it seems flawed: 
Catch `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` event and there replace layout/image_src. 
But I do not know where to get `2x` icon then.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.MyWidget" android:label="@string/widget_to_home" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/myWidgetXml"/>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**myWidgetXml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/myLayout"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/myLayout"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

**myLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/WidgetButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_pic" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WidgetTextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyWidget.java**

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }

    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager _appWidgetManager, int WidgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.myLayout);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        intent.setData(builder.build());
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.WidgetButton, pendingIntent);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.WidgetButton, R.drawable.widget_pic);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.WidgetTextView, "text");
        _appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(WidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the same resolution icon (with highest resolution) in all folders.. It doesn't matter..

Comment: @GokulNC, I like the idea but max size for icon in my app is 800x800px, I guess it won't look crisp on `ldpi` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it impossible to tell android to change resources in runtime
because it loads them during app installation
So there's two options:

- Scale image using `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
- Have 2 sets of resources in each **drawable-*** folder
  (in my case it would be `widget_pic1x1.png` and `widget_pic2x2.png`)